# How to change color of bar in Android App?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I'd like to change color of bar when I use this style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

For example it should looks like system calculator in Android 5, I mean bar on the top is blue.

Comment: have u checked official docs https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you speaking about tool bar. If yes then implement the following xml in your project:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In activity extend your activity to ActionBarActivity, then in onCreate() use  the following code:

```
ToolBar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Make sure you give blue color for colorPrimary attribute in colors.xml file or you can directly give blue color value if you are not using colors.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<item name="background">@color/actionbar_background_color</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `appCompat21` and just set this style:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_darker_color</item>
</style>
```

More info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Comment: Thank you, that helped. In Android Api < 21 status bar is black?

Comment: Yes. The status bar works only for api 21+ currently